How to enable overscroll effect on HTML elements other than the body with Android web browser?
How can I activate the overscroll effect in Android web to indicate reaching the end of a scrollable element (like glow effect or stretching effect)?
It seems like it's automatically applied for root container(body or HTML maybe), but I can't find a way to apply it to nested scrollable elements within. It works well on iOS, but not on Chrome/Firefox on Android.

I'd like overscroll effect to be applied when scrolling div.content in the following code, for example. You can test below code on https://scroll-test.pages.dev/
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="el">
      <div class="content">this is content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<style>
div.el {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  .content {
    height: 800px;
  }
}
</style>

